# Left join query with all possible combinations

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have two tables:

**languages**, as an index of my languages.

```
isolanguage
"de"
"en"
"es"
"fi"
"fr"
"no"
"pl"
"ru"
```

And **translations**, where I store translations of places:

```
Name, translation, isolanguage
"Umeå Airport";"Flughafen Umeå";"de"
"Umeå Airport";"Umeå Airport";"en"
"Umeå Airport";"Aeropuerto de Umeå";"es"
"Umeå Airport";"Uumajan lentoasema";"fi"
```

what I'm trying to get is a list of all elements in translations table for each language in language table.

Expected result:

```
"Umeå Airport";"Flughafen Umeå";"de"
"Umeå Airport";"Umeå Airport";"en"
"Umeå Airport";"Aeropuerto de Umeå";"es"
"Umeå Airport";"Uumajan lentoasema";"fi"
"Umeå Airport";NULL;"fr"
"Umeå Airport";NULL;"no"
"Umeå Airport";NULL;"pl"
"Umeå Airport";NULL;"ru"
```

The point is that I need all languages, having translation or not.

I'm trying a left join query, but is not working, it's only showing elements which are in both tables (excluding NULLS)

```
select * from languages a
left  join translations b
on (a.isolanguage = b.isolanguage)

"Umeå Airport";"Flughafen Umeå";"de"
"Umeå Airport";"Umeå Airport";"en"
"Umeå Airport";"Aeropuerto de Umeå";"es"
"Umeå Airport";"Uumajan lentoasema";"fi"
NULL;NULL;"fr"
NULL;NULL;"no"
NULL;NULL;"pl"
NULL;NULL;"ru"
```

Comment: You must be doing something wrong or different to what you described. I just replicated your setup and the query yielded exactly what you need, including rows with `NULL` for the translation.

Comment: You are right. But what I'm looking for is to have the value of the first field too. for example:
Umeå Airport;NULL;"fr"
Umeå Airport;NULL;"no. If I don't have this field, I'll have a lot of empty fields with "fr" for all the table.

Comment: Well, in that case you need to normalize your schema. Extract the names (first column) into a new table and give them an ID. Then you can query for a cross product of languages and this new table, which will create all possible entries. By left joining that to the translations table, you will get what you need.

Comment: The original question was a bit misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
select name, isolanguage, translation
from (
    select distinct t.name, l.isolanguage
    from translations t
    cross join languages l
    ) t
left join translations
using (name, isolanguage)
order by 1, 2;

     name     | isolanguage |    translation     
--------------+-------------+--------------------
 Umea Airport | de          | Flughafen Umea
 Umea Airport | en          | Umea Airport
 Umea Airport | es          | Aeropuerto de Umea
 Umea Airport | fi          | Uumajan lentoasema
 Umea Airport | fr          | 
 Umea Airport | no          | 
 Umea Airport | pl          | 
 Umea Airport | ru          | 
(8 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

U can use

```
SELECT Name, translation, isolanguage
FROM 
translations
WHERE
language.isolanguage=translation.isolanguage AND
language.isolanguage = 'de' OR
language.isolanguage = 'fr' OR .......
```